# dynamic selectbox to inputbox using materializecss framework and php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, materialize

I create a dynamic select box retrieve from the database. To display in selectbox succeed. However, it can not display data to text input. Please help

```
<form class="col s12" action="" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <?php
                $npm        = $connect->execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_respondent WHERE npm ORDER BY npm ASC");
                $row_count  = $npm->num_rows;
            ?>
            <select name="npm" class="npm">
                <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected>Pilih NPM Anda</option>
                <?php
                    if ($row_count > 0) {
                        while ($row = $npm->fetch_assoc()){
                            echo '<option value="'.$row['npm'].'">'.$row['npm'].'</option>';
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<option value="">NPM tidak tersedia</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <label>Pilih NPM</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="alumni_name" name="name" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="alumni_name">Nama Mahasiswa</label>
        </div>
    </div></form>
```

javascript code is here :

```
 $('select').material_select();
        $('.npm').on('change', function(){
            var npm = $(this).val();
            if (npm) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    url: 'index/npm_search.php',
                    data: 'npm=' + npm,
                    success: function(html){
                        var toAppend = '';
                        $.each(html, function(value){
                           toAppend += '<input id="alumni_name" name="name" type="text" value="'+value.text+'">';
                        });
                        $('#alumni_name').append(toAppend);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $('select').on('contentChanged', function() {
            // re-initialize (update)
            $(this).material_select();
        });
```

and npm_search.php is here:

```
require_once 'apps/model/class.connection.php';

$connect        = new Connection();

if (isset($_GET['npm']) && !empty($_GET['npm']))
{
    $name       = $connect->execute("SELECT * FROM tbl_respondent WHERE npm = ".$_GET['npm']."ORDER BY name ASC");

$row_count  = $name->num_rows;

$return     = [];
$i          = 0;
if ($row_count > 0)
{
    $return[$i] = [
        'id'    => '',
        'text'  => 'Pilih NPM anda',
    ];
    while ($row = $name->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $i++;
        $return[$i] = [
            'text'  => $row['name'],
        ];
    }
}
else {
    $return[$i] = [
        'id'    => '',
        'text'  => 'NPM Tidak tersedia',
    ];
}
echo json_encode($return);
}
```

Comment: Does that first SELECT query actually work? I mean this one `SELECT * FROM tbl_respondent WHERE npm ORDER BY npm ASC`

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We need to know more precisely what is not working

Comment: query working. but, get data from selectbox to textinput not working.

Comment: `success: function(html){
                        var toAppend = '';
                        $.each(html, function(value){
                           toAppend += '<input id="alumni_name" name="name" type="text" value="'+value.text+'">';
                        });
                        $('#alumni_name').append(toAppend);
                    }`

Comment: problem on this source